# Estimate of the nilpotency class from the subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, nilpotent-groups

Let $G$ be a nilpotent group and $H \vartriangleleft G$ a normal subgroup such that $[G:H] \le m$.

Assume $H$ has the nilpotency class $ \le n$. Can we show the nilpotency class of $G$ is bounded by a constant $C$ which depends only on $m$ and $n$?

Comment: Assuming you mean the index, the answer is no. Dihedral 2-groups can have arbitrarily large nilpotency class, but they have abelian subgroups of index 2.

Comment: There's nothing special about the prime $2$, either. If $q$ is a prime power and $p$ is an odd prime divisor of $q-1$, then a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $SL_p(q)$ is of maximal class and has an abelian subgroup of index $p$. The order of $P$ is the $p$-share of $p(q-1)^{p-1}$, which can be arbitrarily large.